# new-item Host-Instance - BizTalk Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell, biztalk, credentials, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to use the Powershell Extensions to BizTalk 2010 to add a Host-Instance (the host already exists).

```
Add-PSSnapIn -Name BiztalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions  #NOTE: Must be in 32-bit version of Powershellto use this SnapIn 
#get-PsSnapIn -registered   ### list registered Snap-In's 

$HostName = "TestNewHost"
$HostType = 1 # 1 = InProcess
$myNTHostGroupName = "BIZTALKDEV\Domain Users" 
$AuthTrusted = $false 
$domainName = "BizTalkDev" 
$serverName = "BizTalkDev"
$defaultAdminUser = "Administrator"

$hostCredentials = $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Logon Credentials","This account must have SQL Server permissions.", $domainName + "\" + $defaultAdminUser, "");
[String]$hostCredentialsPassword = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($hostCredentials.Password)); 


#cd "Biztalk:\Platform Settings\Hosts"
#New-Item $HostName  -HostType:$HostType -NtGroupName:$NTGroupName -AuthTrusted:$AuthTruste
#New-Item -path $hostName -HostType:$HostType -NtGroupName:$NTGroupName -AuthTrusted:$AuthTrusted

cd "BizTalk:\Platform Settings\Host Instances"
dir
Write-Host "Try to add New HostInstance=$hostName"
New-Item $hostName -HostName $hostName -Credentials $hostCredentials -RunningServer $serverName 
dir
```

When I supply a valid domain user/password in the credentials, I get this error:

> New-Item : Instance of the WMI class is not found.
>       No instance was found with the specified key.  This could be the result of the instance being deleted by another BizTalk Admin session.At E:\CreateHost_PSSnapIn.ps1:27 
>       char:1

If I leave off the -Credentials argument.  It prompts me on that new-item for user/pass, and same error occurs.  If I provide a totally bogus userid/pass, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue. I had the wrong value for $servername, should have been "BizTalk2010Dev". I didn't catch that domain name and server name were different (this is a VM that a co-worker created).

So in summary, the error, while very ambiguous, was referring to the existing HostName being missing.  All Host-Instances must be associated with an existing Host.